# Clean way to filter list

Tags: java, list, javafx

I'm making an office application in JavaFX and I've built some sort of filter system to only show people that satisfy certain requirements. Now this uses some TextField's and some CheckBoxes, but I'm looking for a cleaner way to filter the data. I've got this at the moment (and it works) but I'm looking for something better (I have the idea that that should be possible).

```
public ObservableList<Person> filter(ObservableList<Person> original){
    ObservableList<Person> filtered = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    if (filtersEmpty()) {
        return original;
    } else {
        for (Person person : original) {
            boolean hold = true;
            if (!firstNameFilter.getText().equals("") &&
                    !person.getFirstName().toLowerCase().startsWith(firstNameFilter.getText().toLowerCase())) {
                hold = false;
            }

            if (!lastNameFilter.getText().equals("") &&
                    !person.getLastName().toLowerCase().startsWith(lastNameFilter.getText().toLowerCase())) {
                hold = false;
            }

            if (!vibNumberFilter.getText().equals("") &&
                    !person.getVibIdentifier().toLowerCase().contains(vibNumberFilter.getText().toLowerCase())) {
                hold = false;
            }

            if (inGroupCheckBox.isSelected() && !person.getStatus().contains(DataManager.IN_GROUP_STATUS)){
                hold = false;
            }

            if (notOnLinkedInCheckBox.isSelected() && !person.getStatus().contains(DataManager.NO_LINKEDIN_STATUS)){
                hold = false;
            }

            if (workedForVIBCheckBox.isSelected() && !person.getStatus().contains(DataManager.ASKED_WORK_FOR_VIB_STATUS)){
                hold = false;
            }

            if (invitedCheckBox.isSelected() && !person.getStatus().contains(DataManager.INVITED_TO_GROUP_STATUS)){
                hold = false;
            }

            if (placeVIBCheckBox.isSelected() && !person.getStatus().contains(DataManager.ASKED_VIB_ON_CV)){
                hold = false;
            }

            if (placeLogoCheckBox.isSelected() && !person.getStatus().contains(DataManager.ASKED_VIB_LOGO_ON_CV)){
                hold = false;
            }

            if (didWorkForVIBCheckBox.isSelected() && !person.getStatus().contains(DataManager.DID_WORK_FOR_VIB_STATUS)){
                hold = false;
            }

            if (didNotWorkForVIBCheckBox.isSelected() && !person.getStatus().contains(DataManager.DID_NOT_WORK_FOR_VIB_STATUS)){
                hold = false;
            }

            if (hold) {
                filtered.add(person);
            }
        }
    }
    return filtered;
}
```

These UI-elements always have the effect to introduce some sort of code duplication and bad code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use objects to do parts of the filtering for you, the code can be simplified. Furthermore `FilteredList` should be used, since this supports filtering a `ObservableList` and keeping it filtered on updates of the source list as well as replacing the predicate.

```
// initially unfiltered
FilteredList<Person> filteredPersons = new FilteredList<>(allPersons);

// set containing all the predicates that need to match to keep a Person
Set<Predicate<Person>> filters = ...

// keep a person iff all filters return true for the person
Predicate<Person> predicate = person -> filters.stream().allMatch(pred -> pred.test(person));
filteredPersons.setPredicate(predicate);
```

Comment: Thank you! That looks very promissing :) I'm going to give it a go ;)

Comment: I tried it and it's magnificent :) Thank you very much :)